# sending microphone input to wit.ai as stream with java

Tags: java, wit.ai

I'm trying to send my microphone input (which is stored in just an byte array) to wit.ai.

I already succeeded to send an audio file to wit.ai, with the Unirest library.
But I doesn't know how to send it as a stream, for quicker response.

In the documentation it's saying `Put your binary data (file or stream) in the body.`. Do I have to convert my byte array to string and send it just as a normal post? How could I received the "answer" aka. string in the correct order and not broken?

Example: I send `hello my na` and `me is Peter` and I want to get back `hello my name is Peter`